# How to listen to gestures for entire application

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I have an application for which I need to listen tap event on the entire application (not only a single widget). I saw GestureDetector but is there a way to bind it to the entire application and not only to a single widget or page? I mean, I want to listen tap events even if I push/pop routes, show dialogs, etc.